# I'm trying to replace every third element in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace every third element in an array, but my code doesn't work.

```js
 //Calling of the first array
//first array
var numbers = new Array();
var go = true;
while (go) {
  var n = parseFloat(prompt("Number please", ""));
  numbers.push(n);

  go = confirm("One more number?");
}

document.write("<p>" + numbers.toString() + "</p>");

// Array to change elements
// second array
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
  if (numbers[i] % 3 == 0) {
    (numbers *= 2);
  }
else {
  (numbers *= 1);
}
document.write("<p>" + numbers.toString() + "</p>");

//document.write("<p>");
```

Comment: I clicked `<>` for you to create a [mcve]

Comment: For the record, for changing each third element, you could simply alter the loop to have `i` increase with 3, omitting the need for the `if`:   `for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i+=3)
 numbers[i] *= 2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the index in `(numbers[i] *= 2)` and in `(numbers[i] *= 1);`

And to check the third element you need to check the index `(i+1)%3 == 0` because your array starts from index 0;

Answer (score 2):

Change `numbers[i] % 3` to just `i % 3`. You're currently testing if the number in the array is a multiple of three instead of if its position in the array is a multiple of 3.

You also need to change your statements like `numbers *= 2`. `numbers` is an array, so multiplying it doesn't work well. If you want to update the individual array entry that should be `numbers[i] *= 2;`

Comment: Adding to explanation, you do not need `(numbers *= 1);` As an alternative, you can also look into `array.map`. `numbers.map((x,i)=> (i+1)%3 === 0 ? x*2 : x)`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 mistakes apparent in your code:

1. `numbers[i] % 3 == 0`: this implies execute if block for any number a multiple of 3, not at every number on 3rd index
    Solution: `(i + 1) % 3 == 0`
2. `numbers *= 2` : you are trying to multiply **an array** not array element. You will get **NaN**.
    Solution : `numbers[i] *= 2;`

Here's however another way of doing it using map:

```
numbers = numbers.map(function (i, idx) {
    return (idx + 1) % 3 == 0 ? 2*i : i
})
```

Here's a doc to map function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example

Answer (score 0):

You want to check for index, I suppose not number value.

in for loop instead of

`number[i] % 3`

use

```
i % 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You were using `numbers[i]` i.e the actual number instead of the index. So replace `if(number[i]%3==0)` to `if(i%3==0)`.

Secondly, you are updating the whole array instead of an element of array in the if else condition. So use `numbers[i] *=2` instead of `number *= 2`.

Use the below code snippet to change the array:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= numbers.length; i++)
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        numbers[i] *= 2;
    }
    else {
        numbers[i] *= 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: I have made some changes @mplungjan

Comment: Why the else? It does nothing useful

Answer (score 0):

Your logic here is wrong. Instead of taking the modulus of the value you should take the modulus of the index. Instead if `if (numbers[i] % 3 == 0)` this what you should have done is `if (i % 3 == 0)`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the whole program a bit, without using another variable for *go*.

As in comments mentioned, you could iteratig with a step length of 3 and omit the check with the remainder operator `%`.

Aor an assignment to an element of an array, you need the reference to the array with the variable name and the index on the left hand side and an assignment operator and the expression for getting the wanted result.

```
numbers[i] *= 2;
```

```js
var n,
    i,
    numbers = [];
    
do {
    n = parseFloat(prompt("Number please"));
    numbers.push(n);
} while (confirm("One more number?"))

console.log(numbers);
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 3) {
    numbers[i] *= 2;
}
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the mathematical Modulus operator. Every third mean % 3.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp

If you use it in a condition, your index % 3 will return 0 when true.

```
if (index % 3 == 0)
```