# replace alternate elements in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arraylist

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
let number = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or ... 
getNewArray(array, number) {
 // I Need output like below
 result = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] // when user select number 1
 result = [1, null, 3, null, 5, null, 7, null, 9, null]; // when user select number 2
 result = [1, null, null, 4, null, null, 7, null, null, 10]; // when user select number 3
 result = [1, null, null, null, 5, null, null, null, 9, null]; // when user select number 4
 result = [1, null, null, null, null, 6, null, null, null, null]; // when user select number 5
}
```

Based on the user selecting a number, Array of elements should replace with 'null' value.
If user has selected 2, only one null value should display

Comment: Traverse the array and use the modulo operator on its index.

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm trying to replace every third element in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513076)

Comment: `array.map((e,i) => (i%(number) === 0)? e : null)`

Comment: Thank you @cmgchess, Its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function getNewArray(array, number) {
  return array.map((e, i) => (i % number === 0) ? e : null);
}

console.log(...getNewArray(array, 1))
console.log(...getNewArray(array, 3))
console.log(...getNewArray(array, 5))
```